# Run geb tests with firefoxDriver without opening the browser

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, geb

I want to run my Geb specs with firefox driver without opening the browser? can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean run the tests in an existing instance of firefox instead of opening a new one? Or to run it in headless mode?

Comment: Yes headless mode it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where you are running your tests and what you are trying to achieve. 
- If you are running in a *nix system you could use [xvfb](http://tobyho.com/2015/01/09/headless-browser-testing-xvfb/). It supports both the firefox and chrome drivers which is useful because you want to see your tests fail at the same places it would in an open browser. 
- [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html) - I personally have used this for our web applications and have found it pretty easy to set up and configure. Mind you this runs on top of WebKit that both Safari and Chrome use to render web pages.
- [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) - Again built on top a custom Rhino Javascript Engine so you may see different results when running headless and in your browser.

Using your GebConfig.groovy you can configure something like this:

```
environments {
    'headless-ff' {
         driver = {
             pdriver = new PhantomJSDriver(new DesiredCapabilities())
             pdriver.manage().window().maximize()
             pdriver
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try with Phantom JS. I'm thinking is just what I need. Thanks again!!